# Best practices for passing information in android/java

Tags: java, android, calling-convention

Hi I'm writing an app in android and was wondering about best practices and potential advantages and disadvantages of each the methods presented below if you want to call a method defined in Class A from Class B or pass information from class A to B

Method1: Passing Method A as argument.

```
class A {
    B object;
    A(B object) {
        this.object = object;
    }
    void someMethod() {
        object.someOtherMethod();
    }
}
class B {
    void someOtherMethod(){
        ...
    }
}
```

Method2: Defining a interface.

```
class A {
    Helper helper;
    A(Helper helper) {
        this.helper= helper;
    }
    void someMethod() {
        helper.someOtherMethod();
    }
    interface Helper {
        void someOtherMethod();
    }
}
class B implements A.Helper {
    @Override
    void someOtherMethod(){
        ...
    }
}
```

In the android docs I read that the preferred way for passing information from a Fragment to an Activity is the second method. But was wondering why this is the case?

Answer (score 3):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, this sounds more like a question about why/when to use interfaces in OOP.

The best example would be when we add another class, C. If class C implements A.Helper as well, then you can pass C into A no problem, using the second method. If you use the first method, C can not be passed into A, because it is expecting an object of type B.

Some further reading: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/145437/why-use-an-interface-when-the-class-can-directly-implement-the-functions